# Calling python functions with and without print() statement

Tags: python

Earlier I was thinking about something in python for a while and I couldn't think of an answer. Hear me out.

```
def main():
    return 'hello people of stack overflow'
main()
```

VS

```
def main():
    return 'hello people of stack overflow'
print(main())
```

In the first simple program, nothing prints but runs, and the return code is 0. I wonder if python actually runs this program, and if it does, where is the output stored? Thanks

Comment: The first option should print the statement. The second option should print both the statement and "None". How are you running this code

Comment: "In the first simple program, nothing prints but runs, and the return code is 0." - [no, it prints](https://ideone.com/1dpTYF).

Comment: I am sorry I meant to write a return statement

Comment: So in the first case, it is running. By not assigning the function call (`main()`) to a variable (like `result = main()`), python throws away the result because you aren't saving it.

Comment: @RudradipRay  "and if it does, where is the output stored?" *the first program makes no output*. It doesn't print anything. Why would you *expect* any output to be printed?

Comment: The first option creates a string object and returns it, but since it isn't stored anywhere, the string gets deleted.